# Default browser in excel addin

Tags: excel, office-js

I am working on Excel add-in but I am new in office.js.
I would like to know if there is a way to set a browser different from IE 11 as default browser to open the add-in.

I saw the same question on URL below, but I didn´t find if the API mentioned on the answer was developed.
[How to set the default browser in word addin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46906863/how-to-set-the-default-browser-in-word-addin?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid that there is currently no API to determine which browser is used when the add-in is running in desktop Office on Windows. (If it is running in Office Online, then of course it opens in whatever browser you are using.)