# External links are not opening in default browser while using VSTO 2016 word addin

Tags: ms-word, vsto, word-addins

I am using the word 2016 **VSTO addin** with a task pane.

Inside the task pane, I open my website's URL in which there are some external hyper links.

My default browser is Google chrome but still, external links are opening in IE.

I tried with the below URLs.

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/office-wont-open-hyperlinks-in-default-browser/d856aeff-081b-4e26-9626-40b23bf3de42

This below URL is  saying it is not possible

[How to set the default browser in word addin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46906863/how-to-set-the-default-browser-in-word-addin)

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

On the task pane you can use the `LinkLabel` control which allows handling clicks on a link and run the system's default web browser programmatically in the following way:

```
    public void InitializeLinkControl()
    {
        // Create the LinkLabel.
        this.linkLabel1 = new System.Windows.Forms.LinkLabel();

        // Configure the LinkLabel's location. 
        // this.linkLabel1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(34, 56);
        // Specify that the size should be automatically determined by the content.
        this.linkLabel1.AutoSize = true;

        // Add an event handler to do something when the links are clicked.
        this.linkLabel1.LinkClicked += new System.Windows.Forms.LinkLabelLinkClickedEventHandler(this.linkLabel1_LinkClicked);

        // Set the text for the LinkLabel.
        this.linkLabel1.Text = "Visit Microsoft";
    }

    private void linkLabel1_LinkClicked(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Specify that the link was visited.
        this.linkLabel1.LinkVisited = true;

        // Navigate to a URL.
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://www.microsoft.com");
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but we are not doing code on taspane side we are just giving our website URL to open inside a task pane and That external links code in our website which have hyperlink with target="_blank".

Comment: Which browser do you use on a task pane?

Comment: Browsers allows handling hyperlink clicks as well, so you could do the same approach.

Comment: In my website, I have <a href="https://example.com" target="_blank">Support</a> this code and for taskpane I am using WebBrowser.

Comment: Use the `WebView2` browser control on the task pane or/and handle the hyperlink click in the code.