# Can Office.js add-in open an html page from MY domain in the default browser (rather than a new window in Word)?

Tags: ms-office, office-js

Referencing [Open an html page in a default browser from an add-in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38044279/open-an-html-page-in-a-default-browser-from-an-add-in).

Pages that are not on my domain open just fine in the user's default browser.

However, if I open a page on MY domain, which hosts my add-in, I get a floating window (like dialogAPI but I'm not using that in this case).

This is because my manifest's SourceLocation calls out MY website...and Office.js treats the window.open request differently (I guess). Is there a way around this? I would prefer to open support or other resources in a default browser vs. some weird floating window. If I want a weird floating window I'll use dialogAPI.

Comment: are you using `window.open("your-url.com");` or `Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync(url,
    { height: 75, width: 80, requireHTTPS: true });`?

Comment: Using window.open - I would like to stay away from displaydialogAsync. I've found it buggy and it locks the user from doing anything while its open.

Thanks for taking a look!

Comment: Just a thought... In your manifest try to add  `<AppDomains>  <AppDomain>google.com</AppDomain></AppDomains>` and then use `window.open` to open `google.com`... Is the behaviour the same as for your own domain?

Comment: For me it looks like on macOS it always opens the floating window. I am desperately trying to get to the default browser without any luck.