# In Office.js add-in, an html page in a default browser is not opening

Tags: office-js, office-js-helpers

Per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38056639/1232087) suggestion from a Microsoft employee, I tested that the following code in `Home.js` file successfully opens a URL (html page) in a default browser if URL is defined. But if url is left blank, it gives following message by my Windows 10 desktop. I was expecting it to instead display a default `about:blank` page as demonstrated in this [W3schools.com online tutorial page](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_win_open2).

**Following two work in `Home.js`**:

```
window.open('https://www.google.com/','test title');
or
window.open('http://localhost/myWordWebAddIn1Project/SomeHtmlFile.html','test title');
```

**But following in `Home.js` instead displays** the regular Windows 10 message (shown below) asking you to choose an app/program to open the following page:

```
 window.open('','test title');
```

**Message that popups up by Windows 10 when you use the above line in your add-in**:

[image]

**Question**: How can we make the `window.open('','test title');` work in the add-in as well?

NOTE: Please note again, the above line of code works fine in W3Schools online tutorial linked above.

Comment: Why wouldn't you set URL to `about:blank` instead of passing empty string and try? And another more important question: why do you want your user to see empty page at all?

Comment: @SlavaIvanov Your second question is more important. I intend to write data to the page using 1. `var myWindow = window.open('','test title');` and then 2. `myWindow.document.write(…);` But first `1` needs to work before I can get `2` to work. Or, let me know if there is a better way of doing it. Goal is 1. Get html from WORD document 2. Using `jQuery`, reformat that html based on some business needs 3. Dynamically display that reformatted HTML on default browser of Windows desktop. All this needs to be done via `Office.js` add-in for `word`.

Comment: Did you try to use `about:blank` URL? Also you may try to use `/` as URL, not sure what is going to be resolve to under desktop Word.

Comment: @SlavaIvanov Your first suggestion (using `about:blank`) worked (thank you). `/` gave the error `HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden`. Amazing, did not know `about:blank` is a URL. But, thanks to you, now I know.

Comment: `about:` is yet another protocol. Glad it worked out. Best regards.

Comment: @SlavaIvanov Now I want to use `displayDialogAsync(…)`  to open a URL. But this requires a separate post - so, I posted it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52937467/1232087)