# Open a url in the computer default browser Office Add-in

Tags: outlook, ms-office, office-js, outlook-web-addins

I currently have an outlook add-in using Office.js and I could not find a solution on how to open a url in the computers default browser. I looked over the [Open an html page in a default browser from an add-in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38044279/open-an-html-page-in-a-default-browser-from-an-add-in) but none of the solutions helped me where it was indicated to open a new questions if we still have issues.

Currently I have tried to open the url like this:

```
 <div
   className={className}
   onClick={() => window.open(url)}
 >
   {children}
 </div>
```

and

```
<a
  href={url}
  target="_blank"
  rel="noopener noreferrer"
>
  {children}
</a>
```

Unfortunately, both of this examples opens a office dialog with the browser embedded.
The only weird issue is that on the development build, it always opened correct, but not in production. (Office 365 on windows 10)

Comment: Is the url domain the same as the source url domain of the addin? That would cause the link to open a dialog. New windows are opened with Edge if it is the same domain in order to support using cookies to pass data to the window.

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT yes, the url domain is the same as the source url domain. The explains why the development build works because is different urls. Do you have an idea how I can make it work if it's the same url?

Comment: Currently this not part of the product. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our user-voice page. Please add your request there. Feature requests on user-voice are considered, when we go through our planning process.
 https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins